# Cannot override BakeHelper using my plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So far, I've been able to override `ControllerTask`, `ModelTask` and `TemplateTask` in my own plugin by adding and aliasing the parent task. Example using `ModelTask`.

```
namespace WetKit\Shell\Task;
...
use Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask as WetKitModelTask;

class ModelTask extends WetKitModelTask
{...}
```

However, when I attempt to apply the same logic to `BakeHelper.php`, located in `plugin/WetKit/src/View/Helper`, it doesn't work and functionality cannot be found:

```
me@laptop MINGW64 ~/Downloads/xampp3/xampp/htdocs/twofk (master)
$ bin/cake bake controller dummy_lists -t WetKit
*** WetKit Controller Task! ***

Baking controller class for DummyLists...
Warning Error: Method Bake\View\Helper\BakeHelper::isBilingualTable does not exist in [C:\Users\me\Downloads\xampp3\xampp\htdocs\twofk\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper.php, line 116]
```

Here is my custom `BakeHelper` class definition:

```
namespace WetKit\View\Helper;
...
use Bake\View\Helper as WetKitHelper;

/**
 * Bake helper
 */
class BakeHelper extends WetKitHelper
{
    ...

    public function isBilingualTable($table)
       {...}
}
```

This will work if I put the file under the vendor folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers cannot be "overwritten" like tasks, as they are loaded completely different. Tasks are being collected in a list, where tasks collected at a later point can replace existing entries in the list in case they are using the same name.

Helpers are loaded via CakePHP's default helper loading functionality, eg `loadeHelper()`, specifically using a short name that resolves to a fully qualified classname, which cannot be replaced.

Unless you actually want to override any of the bake helper functionality, there's not really a reason to not just use a separate helper, which you can load in the `Bake.initialize` event:

```php
// in your plugin's bootstrap

\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()
    ->on('Bake.initialize', function (\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
        /** @var \Cake\View\View $view */
        $view = $event->getSubject();

        // load `\WetKit\View\Helper\CustomBakeHelper`
        $view->loadHelper('WetKit.CustomBake');
    });
```

The helper can then be used like `CustomBake.isBilingualTable(...)` in the bake twig templates.

For sake of completion, if you actually needed to overwrite the bake helper, you'd first have to unload the existing one, and then load yours:

```php
$view->helpers()->unload('Bake');
$view->loadHelper('WetKit.Bake');
```

See also

- **[Bake Cookbook > Extending Bake](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/development.html)**